# typedef for string alias?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Sorry in advance about the title, I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terms.

```js
/**
 * @return {Object.<string, number>} 
 */
function foo() {}
```

The tooltip in VSCode for the above looks like this:

```js
function foo(): {
    [x: string]: number;
}
```

How can I choose a different label than `x`, like `baz`?  So that it looks like:

```js
function foo(): {
    [baz: string]: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 /**
 * @typedef {{ [baz: string]: number }} Thing
 * @return {Thing} 
 */
function foo() {}
```